# Is it possible to split "Custom Post Types" in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Why does `<!--nextpage-->` work on pages, but not on Custom Post Types?

Here is the code of the single-custom_type.php file.. I added the "`<?php wp_link_pages(); ?>`" by myself. I hoped that would work, but it doesn't. There is nothing more to say actually.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">

<div id="inner-content" class="wrap clearfix">
<div id="main" class="eightcol first clearfix" role="main">
<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/template-logo.php'); ?>
<div class="content">

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix'); ?> role="article">

<header class="article-header">

<h2 class="h2"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

</header> <!-- end article header -->

<section class="entry-content clearfix">
    <?php if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(200,200), array("class" => "alignleft post_thumbnail")); ?>
    </a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>

    <hr>
</section> <!-- end article section -->

<footer class="article-footer">
<p class="tags"><?php the_tags('<span class="tags-title">Tags:</span> ', ', ', ''); ?></p>
</footer> <!-- end article footer -->

<?php // comments_template(); // uncomment if you want to use them ?>

</article> <!-- end article -->

<?php endwhile; ?>          

<?php else : ?>

<article id="post-not-found" class="hentry clearfix">
    <header class="article-header">
        <h1><?php _e("Oops, Post Not Found!", "bonestheme"); ?></h1>
    </header>
    <section class="entry-content">
    <p><?php _e("Uh Oh. Something is missing. Try double checking things.", "bonestheme"); ?></p>
    </section>
    <footer class="article-footer">
        <p><?php _e("This is the error message in the single-custom_type.php template.", "bonestheme"); ?></p>
    </footer>
</article>

<?php endif; ?>
[...]
```

Comment: Are the same theme templates handling all your post types?

Comment: i dont understand what exactly you mean, there is a file named "single-custom_type.php"

Comment: I thought that `<!--nextpage-->` worked by default for CPTs (*but I haven't verified that*). I am trying to figure out if your theme may have done something to disable that functionality, or break it. And the first step is to look at the templates. In your case, yes, there is a different template for that post type. Please post the source of that template. Hopefully it isn't too horribly long :)

Comment: i just posted the source

Comment: Try changing one line and tell me what happens: `<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); setup_postdata(); ?>` I'm not hopeful but call it debugging :)